# Grails vs. ASP.net in Architecture, Response Time and 

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance, grails

I am looking for a good platform to rewrite a growing website with huge amount of daily and concurrent visitors! so the Required Parameters are:

- Render Time With minimum CPU and Memory Usage
- Response Time
- Extendability in Architecture (Best support for new features)
- Maintainability
- Security Capabilities
- Minimum Hardware usage

I know Spring, GORM, but they will slow it down! also I did not mentioned ASP.net MVC because of Tradeoff between Speed and MVC Pattern Benefits!

I know that all of these parameters should be considered as a tradeoff so then I can choose my best fitting platform! Can some body provide a good and reliable comparison between GRails and ASP.net in Items provided above ?

Comment: Anything is going to work if you know the platform well and cache/tune it properly.

Comment: There is no way to answer this question.

Comment: @Gregg why? I Need to know answers of this question to find the best solution for my new Web Site Farm !

Comment: There are just too many variables and the fact that the so called "best" solution is only as good as its implementation.

Comment: @Gregg as you see, I mentioned the parameters witch I want to be compared!